# Show "No result" when there is no post by the user (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type and have a shortcode to make it appear, but I want if there is no post in that custom post, then it should written "No post"... 
Here is code. All things are working on but it don't show "No post" when it's empty.

```
add_shortcode( 'upme_recent_scholarships', 'upme_recent_scholarships',10,2);
function upme_recent_scholarships($display,$id){
global $upme,$upme_options;
$current_options = $upme_options->upme_settings;

$id = $upme->current_view_profile_id;
$post_limit = $current_options['maximum_allowed_posts'];
$feature_image_status = $current_options['show_feature_image_posts'];
$args = array(
    'author' => $id,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'scholarship',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_limit,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {



    $display .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">';

    // Display different views based on posts with featured images or posts as text
    if ('1' == $feature_image_status) {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
            $image_src = upme_url . 'img/default-post-thumbnail.png';
            if (is_array($image_attributes) && ('' != $image_attributes[0])) {
                $image_src = $image_attributes[0];
            }

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field upme-post-list-field">
                <div class="upme-post-feature-image"><img src="' . $image_src . '" /></div>
                <div class="upme-post-feature-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
             </div>';

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    } else {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field ">
                    <div class="upme-post-field-type"><i class="upme-icon upme-icon-file-text"></i></div>
                    <div class="upme-post-field-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
                 </div>';
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    }

    $display .= '</div>';
}

return $display;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Did you checked my below code?

Comment: Yeah, Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this modified script, Please check shortcode parameter, here I have updated correct method.

```
    add_shortcode( 'upme_recent_scholarships', 'upme_recent_scholarships',10,2);
function upme_recent_scholarships($atts){
global $upme,$upme_options;
$current_options = $upme_options->upme_settings;
$display = $atts['display'];
$id = $atts['id'];
$id = $upme->current_view_profile_id;
$post_limit = $current_options['maximum_allowed_posts'];
$feature_image_status = $current_options['show_feature_image_posts'];
$args = array(
    'author' => $id,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'scholarship',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_limit,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {



    $display .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">';

    // Display different views based on posts with featured images or posts as text
    if ('1' == $feature_image_status) {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
            $image_src = upme_url . 'img/default-post-thumbnail.png';
            if (is_array($image_attributes) && ('' != $image_attributes[0])) {
                $image_src = $image_attributes[0];
            }

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field upme-post-list-field">
                <div class="upme-post-feature-image"><img src="' . $image_src . '" /></div>
                <div class="upme-post-feature-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
             </div>';

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    } else {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field ">
                    <div class="upme-post-field-type"><i class="upme-icon upme-icon-file-text"></i></div>
                    <div class="upme-post-field-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
                 </div>';
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    }

    $display .= '</div>';
}else{
/*need to add this*/    
 $display .= '<p>Sorry!, No Record Found</p>';
}

return $display;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It worked, Thank you. I didn't add shortcode where I was wanted to show it.. Just noticed and added. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Code

```
add_shortcode( 'upme_recent_scholarships', 'upme_recent_scholarships',10,2);
function upme_recent_scholarships($display,$id){
global $upme,$upme_options;
$current_options = $upme_options->upme_settings;

$id = $upme->current_view_profile_id;
$post_limit = $current_options['maximum_allowed_posts'];
$feature_image_status = $current_options['show_feature_image_posts'];
$args = array(
    'author' => $id,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'scholarship',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_limit,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {



    $display .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">';

    // Display different views based on posts with featured images or posts as text
    if ('1' == $feature_image_status) {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
            $image_src = upme_url . 'img/default-post-thumbnail.png';
            if (is_array($image_attributes) && ('' != $image_attributes[0])) {
                $image_src = $image_attributes[0];
            }

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field upme-post-list-field">
                <div class="upme-post-feature-image"><img src="' . $image_src . '" /></div>
                <div class="upme-post-feature-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
             </div>';

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    } else {

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $display .= '<div class="upme-field ">
                    <div class="upme-post-field-type"><i class="upme-icon upme-icon-file-text"></i></div>
                    <div class="upme-post-field-value"><span><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></span></div>
                 </div>';
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    }

    $display .= '</div>';
}else{

 $display .= '<p>No Post Found</p>';
}
wp_reset_query();
return $display;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot  :D

Comment: Done. Thank you :D

Comment: I think that is not possible